# Creating Pivot Table c# interop

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, interop

I am trying to **create a Pivot Table** from a full Worksheet with **C#** interop but I am getting some errors, don't know if is my code or this example is old.

I am following this *example*: [Creating a Pivot Table c#](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Pivot-Table-Create-Pivot-Table-in-Excel-with-C-/VB.NET.html)

But when I try it, I can't find some methods.
This is my code:

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            Workbooks libro = Excel.Workbooks;
            Workbook libroActual = libro.Add();
            Sheets sheets = libroActual.Worksheets;

            //Excel.Workbooks.Add();

            // Instanciamos la hora activa
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet Worksheet = Excel.ActiveSheet;
            Worksheet.Name = "Desglose";

            Worksheet sheetMMPP = Excel.Worksheets.Add();
            sheetMMPP.Name = "MMPP";// CreateEmptySheet(); 

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range dataRange = Worksheet.UsedRange;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCache cache = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCache)libroActual.PivotCaches().Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase,dataRange);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable pt = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable)sheetMMPP.PivotTables().Add("Pivot Table", Worksheet.Range["A1"], cache);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField oPivotField = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField)pt.PivotFields("Nivel 0");
            oPivotField.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
            oPivotField.Function = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum;
            oPivotField.Name = "Nivel 0";
```

But I get this error:

> Could not convert argument 2 for call to Add

The error is in this line:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable pt = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable)sheetMMPP.PivotTables().Add("Pivot Table", Worksheet.Range["A1", "P56"], cache);
```

Someone knows about this error?

Comment: Pivot table need to be against a worksheet not a workbook. libroActual is a workbook.

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your comment. I've edited the post.

Comment: Are you trying to grab just cells A1 and P56?

Comment: Hi @Jacob I've edited the post with the error!

Comment: The reason I am asking is because the error line you have isn't in the code snippet you provided. In the question you have the line pt = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable)sheetMMPP.PivotTables().Add("Pivot Table", Worksheet.Range["A1"], cache);


You say the error is pt = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable)sheetMMPP.PivotTables().Add("Pivot Table", Worksheet.Range["A1", "P56"], cache);

Comment: Where it fails what is the active worksheet in excel.  From my experience the error is due to adding from the wrong worksheet.  So the active worksheet may be changing. So rather the use Worksheet.Range["A1"] I would use sheets.Range["A1"].  Also be careful the Sheets and Worksheets are different and my cause issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've mixed up libraries. In your link, the example is based on the Spire.xls library, but in the code you use Interop.Excel with Spire syntax. The Interop.Excel PivotTables.Add method has different parameters - `Add (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCache PivotCache, object TableDestination, [object TableName], [object ReadData], [object DefaultVersion])`